# Running gnome-keyring on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: git, gnome-keyring, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to store HTTPS GIT credentials using a Keyring (Gnome Keyring) using the steps in this article:

http://blog.iqandreas.com/git/storing-https-authentication-in-ubuntu-and-arch-linux/

I took these steps:

```
sudp apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install-gnome-keyring-dev
sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

Now when I use any remote git command, I get the error:

```
** (process:19273): CRITICAL **: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon
```

Is it just not possible to run a daemon on WSL, or am I missing something simple? Sorry if this is a different type of question, I'm new on Ubuntu.

On another note, would it be a good idea to create a synonym 'WSL' for the tag 'ubuntu-on-windows'?

I think this might become the most logical acronym for ubuntu-on-windows: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/

UPDATE:

I've tried what @LordMord said:

> add at the end of ~/.bashrc

```
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
  test -r ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    source ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL SSH_AUTH_SOCK GPG_AGENT_INFO GNOME_KEYRING_PID

  ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
  if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
    (umask 066; echo `dbus-launch --sh-syntax` > ~/.gnome-keyring; gnome-keyring-daemon >> ~/.gnome-keyring)
    source ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL SSH_AUTH_SOCK GPG_AGENT_INFO GNOME_KEYRING_PID
  fi
fi
```

And it told me to install 2 more dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring
```

but now I get this error on startup:

```
** (gnome-keyring-daemon:23): WARNING **: couldn't create socket directory: No such file or directory

** (gnome-keyring-daemon:23): WARNING **: couldn't bind to control socket: /home/wtijsma/.cache/keyring-3mToEe/control: No such file or directory
```

And this error when I try to use a remote GIT command:

```
Gkr-Message: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

Comment: I ended up just following his security conscious recommendation of using a long credential timeout so at least I only need to type it once a day.

Comment: You might have an advice here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/905658/wsl-cant-scp-ssh-a-file-from-a-remote-machine-to-a-local-machine

Answer (score 2):

add at the end of ~/.bashrc

```
ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
  test -r ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    source ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL SSH_AUTH_SOCK GPG_AGENT_INFO GNOME_KEYRING_PID

  ssh-add -l &>/dev/null
  if [ "$?" == 2 ]; then
    (umask 066; echo `dbus-launch --sh-syntax` > ~/.gnome-keyring; gnome-keyring-daemon >> ~/.gnome-keyring)
    source ~/.gnome-keyring && \
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL SSH_AUTH_SOCK GPG_AGENT_INFO GNOME_KEYRING_PID
  fi
fi
```

Credentials are automatically added to ssh-agent provided that both the public and private keys are inside ~/.ssh.
Keychain storing applications such as mysql-workbench(requires Xming) also work.

You can ignore this warning on bash startup

```
gnome-keyring-daemon: insufficient process capabilities, unsecure memory might get used
```

source:
https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/4yhch4/using_gnomekeyringdaemon_for_ssh_keys/

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it didn't work for me, see update :(

Comment: Here's an adaptation to fish shell: https://gist.github.com/kppullin/93ecf587d91b40f30ca0f1f374fbc6ee .  Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the modifications in your .bashrc

Install keyrings.alt

`sudo pip install keyrings.alt`

Comment: Some more details about how to set this up would be appreciated. Does gnome-keyring use this or does this take the place of gnome-keyring? Do I need to do anything with git config to use it?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels: 1. `sudo pip install` to break your system python installation (keyrings.alt is packaged in Debian & Ubuntu, so installing the package `python-keyrings.alt` or `python3-keyrings.alt` is enough. 2. This will only help if the tool you are using is using the Python keyring package, otherwise this is no fix at all

Answer (score 1):

You can find the keyring official document about [Using Keyring on headless Linux systems](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems). This would work on WSL, Docker containers and all other headless Linux. Here is more concise instructions.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install -y gnome-keyring python3-pip
$ pip3 install -U --user pip keyring
$ dbus-run-session -- sh # this will drop you into a new D-bus shell
$ echo 'any_password' | gnome-keyring-daemon --unlock # unlock the system's keyring
$ keyring set system user # enter any thing
$ keyring get system user
```

If you just need a security service, then you can use "keyrings.alt" Python package instead of gnome-keyring. gnome-keyring was made for X11
GUI, so it is a bit painful to make it work with non-GUI. keyrings.alt is made for non-GUI. You can install keyrings.alt as follows.

```
pip3 install -U --user keyrings.alt
```

"keyrings.alt" has security risks. It shouldn't be used in production environment

Comment: Your link is invalid