# How can I get a credential store running in WSL Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnome-keyring, kwallet

I am trying to utilize a Go program called [aws-okta](https://github.com/segmentio/aws-okta) which makes use of another Go program called [keyring](https://github.com/99designs/keyring). The latter "provides a common interface to a range of secure credential storage services," including KDE Wallet, the Windows Credential Manager, and the macOS Keychain. However I'm trying to utilize this program from WSL Ubuntu, which means it's detecting Linux and so tries to use KDE Wallet as its credential store.

I tried installing a couple of packages from apt such as gnome-keyring, lib-secret-1-0, and lib-secret-1-dev. I also tried running the `make` and `git config` commands detailed in this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/815327).

However, when I run the program, it now says:

> The name org.kde.kwalletd was not provided by any .service files

I then tried installing `kwalletmanager` and ended up with this error:

> Failed to execute program org.kde.kwalletd: No such file or directory

Is there any way to get a valid credential store working in WSL Ubuntu? Or any other alternative way to get the program above working?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KWallet. I don't know about WSL Ubuntu. But on "regular" desktop Ubuntu flavors, you'll need, at a minimum, to install `kwalletmanager` and all the dependencies it needs.

Comment: I just installed kwalletmanager, and now the error I get is "Failed to execute program org.kde.kwalletd: No such file or directory."